# My mkdir() function tells me I don't have permission

Tags: php, upload, mkdir, permission-denied

I am trying to create a directory that stores all the user's profile pictures. Whenever I click the Upload button it says :
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testing/account_settings.php on line 60

Here is the mkdir() code:

```
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");
```

I tried changing the permissions:

```
mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name", 0777);
```

I still get Permission denied. What am I doing wrong?

PS: Full code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
    if (((@$_FILES['profilepic'] ['type']=='image/jpeg') || (@$_FILES['profilepic']     ['type']=='image/png') || (@$_FILES['profilepic'] ['type']=='image/gif')) &&     (@$_FILES['profilepic'] ['size'] < 1048576)) {
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
        mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name", 0777);
    } else {
    echo "Upload failed";
    }
}
?>
```

Upload form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <img src="<?php echo $profile_pic; ?>" width="70"><br>
    <input type="file" name="profilepic"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="uploadpic" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name", 0777);
```

will only set the permissions for the newly created directory. You need to change the permissions of the directory you are trying to create the folder in.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cd into your profile pics directory first (and also make sure you have write permissions in there), then create the directory in there.

```
chdir('userdata/profile_pics'); // Make sure this is writable
mkdir($rand_dir_name, 0755);
```

Unless you want to make the folder globally writable by any user on your system, chmod 755 should be enough to allow uploading into the directory by the web server.

Comment: @user2848575 Is the folder relative to the current directory in which the PHP script resides? If not, use full paths or traverse accordingly. For example if the userdata directory is 2 levels higher than your current directory use `chdir('../../userdata/profile_pics');` With your current code, the userdata directory should be in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testing/`.